# ResolveMethod() Returning Completely Different Method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was resolving methods from .NET DLLs, and noticed that the method being returned by Module.ResolveMethod() is completely different from original method. I am specifying the method's exact MetadataToken, so it makes absolutely no sense to me why I would end up with anything else but the original method.

In the below example, I have the 'Dispose()' method. I grab its metadata token and resolve it, only to find that I now have the 'OnBackColorChanged(System.EventArgs)'method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        MethodInfo method = assembly.GetModules()[0].GetTypes()[300].GetMethods()[362];
        Console.WriteLine(method); //Returns 'Void Dispose()'

        MethodInfo method2 = (MethodInfo)assembly.GetModules()[0].ResolveMethod(method.MetadataToken);
        Console.WriteLine(method2); //Returns 'Void OnBackColorChanged(System.EventArgs)' ...why?
    }
```

Comment: What type is `GetTypes()[300]`?

Comment: @InBetween System.Windows.Forms.Button

Comment: I assume so. It only happens to some methods, and I've tried comparing the methods which are affected to the ones that aren't and haven't found any notable differences

Comment: @mjwills I think it only returns one module in this case anyways, doesn’t it?

Comment: You are switching context here. `Void Dispose()` is in System.dll. If you: `Assembly.LoadFrom(@"...\System.dll")`, then `ResolveMethod(method.MetadataToken)` will correctly return `Void Dispose()`. So, verify that `method.Module.Name` is the same before trying to resolve a  MetadataToken.

Comment: @Jimi If Void Dispose is in System.DLL, then why is it being picked up as a method within System.Windows.Forms.Button?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.dll` has three Dependencies: System.dll, System.Drawing.dll and System.Core (mscorlib.dll).  From mscorlib it imports, for example, `GetHashCode` and `GetType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button`, through long inheritance chain, inherits from `Component` class, which implements `IDisposable` and has `void Dispose()` method. This is the method you obtain via

```
assembly.GetModules()[0].GetTypes()[300].GetMethods()[362];
```

Since this method is declared on type `Component`, which is located in `System` assembly - no surprise that using its metadata handle to resolve method from completely different module (`System.Windows.Forms`) leads to random results.

If you want to get only methods declared on this concrete type - use `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`:

```
var allMethods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

But note this will return only methods declared on `Button`, not on any parent type, even if that parent type belongs to the same module.

Alternatively - filter by module:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll");
var module = assembly.GetModules()[0];
var type = module.GetTypes()[300];
var allMethods = type.GetMethods().Where(c => c.Module == module).ToArray();
```

Comment: Very thorough and high-quality answer. Thanks for helping out!